# How is $a_j'= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_{ij}a_i$ shouldn't it be $a_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n P_{ij}a_j'$? Hoffman and Kunze theorem 2.4.8

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

How is $a_j'= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_{ij}a_i$ shouldn't it be $a_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n P_{ij}a_j'$

I tried my best to understand how this is true and I spent more than an hour here

[image]

> another question is what is $k$ in $a_k$ and what does it even show ?

this proof took me a lot of time and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I agree with you, maybe he's using different conventions than those we use today and he's multiplying on the left?

Comment: [Please don't use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Comment: $k$ in $a_k$ is the number of the vector $a_k$ in the basis $\mathcal B=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. What does disturb you here?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I will try write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are correct. This is the standard change of basis machinery. It is perhaps unfortunate, however, that they use the letter $\alpha$ for the general vector in $V$ and also write $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ (and $\alpha'_1,\dots,\alpha'_n$) for bases.

The columns of $P$ give the coefficients of the primed basis expressed as linear combinations of the unprimed basis. They then show that the columns of $Q=P^{-1}$ give the coefficients of the unprimed basis expressed as linear combinations of the primed basis. It often confuses students at the beginning, but the coordinates of a vector transform the opposite of the way the basis vectors transform: The vector of coefficients of an arbitrary *vector* in the primed basis is given by multiplying $P^{-1}$ (not $P$) by the vector of coefficients in the unprimed basis.

It helps to keep the following fundamental principle in mind: When you multiply a matrix $A$ by a vector $x$, the answer is a linear combination (with coefficients $x_j$) of the *columns* of $A$.
At any rate, their computaton shows that the $k$th vector $\alpha_k$ of the original basis is obtained by taking the linear combination of the vectors $\alpha'_j$ given by the $k$th column of the matrix $Q$.

If you cannot understand their proof, you might want to look at [my YouTube video on change of basis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiP7bITeR9o&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=103&t=19s).

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome answer and this awesome video

Comment: I did the following steps 
let  $[ a ]_{\mathcal{B}} = \{x_1 ,\dots x_n \}$ with coordinates $v_i$ and $[ a ]_{\mathcal{B'}} = \{y_1 ,\dots y_n \}$ with coordinates $u_j$

$$x_i = \sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij} y_j$$
$$a= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i = \sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i) y_j=\sum_{j=1}^n y_j u_j  $$

this will somehow lead to $u_j = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i$ right?

Did I understand correctly ? If not I hope you explain to me

and if I was correct how would  this lead to $u_j = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i$ ?

Comment: I just realised  I don't know what $P$ Is . The original text don't mention what it is

Comment: @pie It's in the first sentence :) I do not follow your second line of equations. Nor do I understand what your "with coordinates $v_i$" and $u_j$ means. Those are basis vectors.

Comment: I don't understand what $[a]_B$ mean does it mean  coordinate of general $\{x_1 , x_2 \}$ or does it mean the base $a_1, a_2, \dots $? in my equations $ v_i$ is the base and also $u_i$ and I dont know what $P$ is in the exercise $P$  have the base $v_i$ as thir column vector

Comment: @pie Since you started commenting on someone else's post with your own questions, maybe you should either read Hoffman-Kunze so the post makes sense or else post your own question.

Comment: I did https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844130/what-is-p-in-theorem-2-4-8-hoffman-and-kunze