# What is $P$ in Theorem 2.4.8 Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, proof-explanation, change-of-basis

Code borrowed from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286369/theorem-relating-to-change-of-basis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Suppose $P$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix over $F.$ Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F,$ and let $\cal B$ be an ordered basis of $V.$ Then there is a unique ordered basis $\cal \overline{B}$ of $V$ such that

$$(i)[\alpha]_{\mathcal{B}} = P [\alpha]_{\mathcal{ \overline{B}}}$$
$$(ii) P^{-1}[\alpha]_{\mathcal{B}} = [\alpha]_{\mathcal{ \overline{B}}}$$

for every vector $\alpha \in V$

proof : Let $\cal B$ consist of the vectors $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n.$ Let $\cal \overline{B}= \{\overline{\alpha_1},\dots ,\overline{\alpha_n}\}$ be an ordered set in which $[\alpha]_{\mathcal{B}} = P [\alpha]_{\mathcal{ \overline{B}}}$
, $\color{red}{\text{it is clear that $\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum P_{i,j}\alpha_i$}}$

Thus we need only show that the vectors $\overline{\alpha_j},$ defined by these equations form a basis. Let $Q=P^{-1}.$ Then
\begin{align}
\sum_j Q_{jk}\overline{\alpha_{j}}&=\sum_j Q_{jk}\sum_i P_{ij}\alpha_i\\
&=\sum_j \sum_iP_{ij}Q_{jk}\alpha_i\\
&=\sum_i\Big( \sum_jP_{ij}Q_{jk}\Big)\alpha_i\\
&=\alpha_k
\end{align}

Thus the subspace spanned by the set $\cal \overline{B}$ contains $\cal B$ and hence spans $V.$ Thus $(1)$ is valid due to a previous theorem.

---

I want to ask what is $P$? Is it any $n \times n$ invertible  matrix or a unique one that relate $\alpha_k'$ to $\alpha_k$?

In page 51 $\overline{\alpha} _j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_{ij} \alpha_i $ does it have the same meaning in this theorem or it is just any general matrix ?
for example in the exercise there is this question

> 3. Let $\mathcal {B}$ =$\{a_1, a_2,a_3\}$ as be the ordered basis for $R^3$ consisting of
>    $a_1 = (1, 0, - 1)$, $a_2 = (1, 1, 1),$ $a_3 = (1, 0, 0)$.
>    What are the coordinates of the vector (a, b, c) in the ordered basis $ \cal B$?

in the answer

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  1    &  1
\\\\ 0  &  1   &  0
\\\\ -1   &  1   &  0
\end{pmatrix}$$
If not then how to prove $\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n P_{ij}\alpha_i$?

another question is what is $[\alpha]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is it the base vector $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n $ or a coordinate of a vector $\alpha $ according to base $ \cal B $? (using the same notation for general vector and the base confuses me a lot)

---

I apologise if the question seemed elementary or stupid but I am a beginner in this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the causality mixed up. The theorem content is the following:

> **Hypotheses**: Given the invertible matrix $P$ and the basis $\mathcal{B}$ .
>
> **Conclusions**: There exists a unique basis $\overline{\mathcal{B}}$ such that the stated equation holds (equivalently, such that $P_{\mathcal{B}}^{\overline{\mathcal{B}}}=\mathrm{Id}_n$).

Whereas you seemed to be worrying about this:

> **Hypotheses**: Given the bases $\mathcal{B},\overline{\mathcal{B}}$.
>
> **Conclusions**: There exists an unique invertible matrix $P$ such that the stated equation holds.

*This is also true* but it has a different proof and is the converse of what the text is showing. The linked "question $3$" you show is an example of the converse: we're given the two bases and then we need to find the change of basis matrix.

So "what is $P$?" It is indeed 'anything' (invertible and of the right dimension). You ask how to prove $\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum P_{i,j}\alpha_i$. *You don't*. It's true by definition! The authors defined $\overline{\alpha_j}$ by that equation.

Comment: then what is $[a]_{\cal B}$? (using the same notation for general vector and the base confuses me a lot)

and how is $\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum P_{i,j}\alpha_i$ true by definition ?

Comment: @pie Verbatim from your post:

> ... an ordered set in which each element is defined by:
$\begin{align}
\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n P_{ij}\alpha_i, 1\le j\le n
\end{align}$

So yes, it's true by definition.

Comment: I don't understand your first objection unfortunately ("same notation for general vector and the base": they use $\mathcal{B}$ to mean the basis $\mathcal{B}$ and only that). They explain the meaning of $[a]_{\mathcal{B}}$; it's given in your post. Is there something more specifically in the definition that you don't understand?

Comment: the post I borrowed the code from changed this 

in the text it is ", it is clear that $\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum P_{i,j}\alpha_i$" in the code I borrowed it is "  which each element is defined by:$ \overline{\alpha_j}=\sum P_{i,j}\alpha_i$"

Comment: @pie Then it may have been a good idea to mention that in your question, since the "it is clear that" seems to be the thing which is troubling you. What the authors mean is this: *if we expect the theorem to be true, it is clear that we should define the $\overline{\alpha_j}$ in this way*. It is more logically and pedagogically correct however to say: "Let's define $\overline{\alpha_j}=\cdots$" and then perhaps say a few words about why that is a good definition.

Comment: I didn't notice It was changed But now I edited it

Comment: from the text It didn't see to mean "we will define $\overline{\alpha}$ this way " it seemed to be a true statement that is based from the definition of $\overline{\alpha}$  and $\alpha $ so this what made me expect that $P$ is a unique matrix not a general one 

I tried to prove this from the definition of $\overline{\alpha}$  and $\alpha $  but it was impossible

Comment: @pie That's fair enough. Some context clues: the $\overline{\alpha}$ are not defined before that, so the first appearance of an equation they satisfy is likely to be a definition. Also, they later say "... defined that way". But I agree, it's not written in the clearest way - but hopefully it makes sense now?

Comment: Yeah it is clear now, Thank you very much! I wouldn't ever realise that without your answer I could spent days, weeks or even months stuck there and eventually skip this part